# Неверно работает рекурсивный алгоритм. Delphi

Tags: delphi, pascal, рекурсия

Когда ввожу число, в котором больше 2-х разрядов, функция постоянно возвращает false. В чем ошибка? Функция вычисляет кратно ли число по признаку делимости на 11

```
function isMultiple(x : integer) : boolean;
var i, f : integer;
begin
  sum1 := sum1 + x mod 10;
  x := x div 10;
  sum2 := sum2 + x mod 10;
  x := x div 10;

  if (x > 0) then
    isMultiple(x)
  else
    if (sum1 - sum2 mod 11 = 0) or (sum1 = sum2) then
      result := true
    else
      result := false;
end;
```

Comment: А почему сразу нельзя просто сделать `result := x mod 11 = 0;`

Comment: Функция проверяет кратность числав на 11 используя признак делимости

Comment: и смысла от рекурсии я тут честно говоря не вижу. Но проблема - нужно писать `result := isMultiple(x)`

Comment: Потому что во-первы result это логическая переменаая, а во вторых все через рекурсию надо

Comment: Что такое `sum1` и `sum2`, которые нигде у Вас не описаны и не инициализированы? И зачем объявлены переменные `i` и `f`, которые никак не используются?

Comment: ну во-первых я понимаю что она логическая, и вроде всё правильно написал, а во-вторых пихать рекурсию где она совсем не нужна это плохо говорит об учителе. А как проблему решить я написал.

Comment: Так у меня препод отъехавщий

Comment: @Ник думаю тут есть еще одна проблема `sum1 - sum2 mod 11 = 0` нужно сделать `(sum1 - sum2) mod 11 = 0` так как сначала делает mod

Answer (score 2):

Ваша проблема - вы не возвращаете ничего из функции при рекурсивном вызове. (Хорошие IDE это должны были подсказать).

Для исправления нужно сделать `result := isMultiple(x)` тогда скорее всего работать будет.

Но честно говоря код не очень красивый, я бы написал так и без рекурсии:

```
function isDivide11(x :ansistring) : boolean;
var i : LongWord;
    s : byte;
begin
   i:= Length(x);
   s:=0;
   if (odd(i)) then begin
      s := 11 + ord(x[i]) - ord('0'); 
      dec(i);
   end;
   while (i > 0) do begin
       s:= 11 + s+ord(x[i-1]) - ord(x[i]);
       s:= s mod 11;
       dec(i,2); 
   end;
   isDivide11:= (s = 0);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
function isMultiple(x : integer) : boolean;
var i, f : integer;
begin
  sum1 := sum1 + x mod 10;
  x := x div 10;
  sum2 := sum2 + x mod 10;
  x := x div 10;

  if (x > 0) then
    result := isMultiple(x)
  else
    result := ((sum1 - sum2) mod 11 = 0);
end;
```

После проверки `x > 0` нужно продолжить рекурсию и вернуть результат

А тут `(sum1 - sum2) mod 11 = 0` нужно сначала получить разницу, потом проверить.

Comment: `or (sum1 = sum2)` уберите уже, толку то от него, и `if ... then result := true` глаза режет

Comment: исправил, спасибо